# How to rewrite domainname.com/index.php/dir/controller/?var1=abc&var2=def

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to rewrite `domainname.com/index.php/dir/controller/?var1=abc&var2=def`

to

`domainname.com/rewrite-string/abc/def/`?

`domainname.com/rewrite-string/abc/def/` is link that user put to browser address bar

and server will redirect it to `domainname.com/index.php/dir/controller/?var1=abc&var2=def`.

Answer (score 0):

to get querystring values, you need to use a `RewriteCond` like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var1=([^&]*)&var2=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^index.php/dir/controller$  /rewrite-string/%1/%2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and reference matching groups by `%` not `$`

Comment: no problem. There are many sites out there that explain htaccess rewrites and regular expressions. I liked this one, hopefully it helps you too http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php